# Geometry: Proof related to right angled isosceles triangle

Tags: proof-writing, triangles

ABC is a right angled isosceles triangle. If AD is a bisector of angle BAC then prove that AC + CD = AB.

[The right angled isosceles triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaQOg.png)

The right angle is at C.

Comment: Is the right angle located in $C$?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Are you sure of that?

Comment: Yes I am sure. The right angle is at C. @Dr. Sonnhard Graunber

Comment: I figured out each individual angle but other than that I don't have anything. @Matt

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How did you equate AC and CD? ABC is the isosceles triangle here, not ADC.

Answer (score 0):

After a Theorem of the angle bisector we get
$$BD:DC=\sqrt{2}a:a$$
or
$$\frac{a-DC}{DC}=\sqrt{2}$$
simplifying this we get
$$DC=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}+1}$$
so $$a+\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}+1}=a$$
and this is true
since
$$\sqrt{2}a+2a=2a+\sqrt{2}a$$
Where $$AC=BC=a$$ and $$AB=\sqrt{2}a$$

Comment: Sorry it was just a typo!

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an **isosceles** right triangle the two acute angles are $\pi/4$ radians.  We can, without loss of generality, take sides AC and BC to have length 1 so that AB has length $\sqrt{2}$.  Bisecting angle A gives an angle of $\pi/8$ radians and DC has length $\tan(\pi/8)$ $= \frac{sin(\pi/4)}{1+ cos(\pi/4)}= \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{1+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2+ \sqrt{2}}$.

$AC+ CD= 1+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2+ \sqrt{2}}= \frac{2                                      + 2\sqrt{2}}{2+ \sqrt{2}}= \frac{4+ 4\sqrt{2}- 2\sqrt{2}- 4}{4- 2}= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2}= \sqrt{2} $